# Aurelia Dialog not working when creating a custom aurelia plugin

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

I can’t get the aurelia dialog plugin to work properly in my custom aurelia plugin. The idea is to use my custom aurelia plugin for common modals that I can re-use for different aurelia projects.

I have [setup a mininmal](https://github.com/dtaalbers/aurelia-plugin-with-dialog) plugin project that gives me errors when opening a modal. See the screenshot below for the errors that you can reproduce in the example project when clicking the button (note: the second console error is delayed a bit when clicking the button).

- Clone the project.
- Install dependencies with npm i.
- Run the project with npm start.
- Navigate to http://localhost:9000 and click the button.

[image]

Also when I make changes to a typescript file that is located in the dev-app, and save the changes, I get a typescript error in my console which I don’t understand and don’t know how to solve.

[image]

Appreciate any help!